A vectorized solution for stacking a tensor along an specific dimension
Suppose I have tensor with size [2, 64, 64], I want to stack it either horizontally or vertically along the first dimension, so I want to stack [0,:,:] and [1,:,:] and get a [128,64] or a [64,128] tensor.
Clearly this is possible with looping over the first dimension of tensor, but I'm looking for a vectorized solution instead of for-loop solution, any idea?
And also another general quesion, asking for advice honestly! , I really don't know how can I improve my coding in a vectorized manner, I mean I usually use for-loops as a solution but it seems using for-loop is not recommended in terms of performance, how can I learn to code in a vectorized manner?
I tried to use concat or vstack but didn't succeed.

Does A.reshape(128,64) give you what you want?

@jared it does, but it's hard coded in some way, we don't know the exact dimensions. we just know last two dimensions are the same. that's all.

Please edit your question to include a reproducible example and explain what you do and don't know about the tensors.

It sounds like A.reshape(-1, A.shape[-1]) might be a more general approach to what you want.

If you have an array with shape (a,b,c), you can reshape to (a*b,c) or (a,b*c).  And use -1 as one of those dimensions (see docs).  To get (a*c,b) you have to transpose b and c.

np.concatenate and its family of stack functions will treate the array as a list of a (b,c) arrays.  With concatenate you can specify the join axis.  vstack will be same as .reshape(-1,c).

Did you try np.hstack(arr) to get the (64,128) case?  or np.concatenate(arr,axis=1)?
